# About In-App purchase between devices and apps

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to share a question about In-App Purchases

I have some maps applications where I'm trying to add In-App Purchases to let user buy different map layers to show in the application. I want to let users buy the In-App Purchases in the same app to get new map layers, and I want to show other layers that they buy in another application from us too. And I want to show all the IAP that user purchased in different devices.

The way I want to do this is using a Server Product Model, where an app will send some information to our server when the user buy a IAP. When we want to get the user IAP purchased for show all the IAPs that user have, I request the info to our server to know if there are another purchases for this user in other apps of us and if it is, we will show another extra layers in the map.

The problem I have is that seems that is not possible to get the user account because is private data, and we need to get this information for some reasons:

- To detect if the same user is connected in another device because we can show all the IAP the user purchase in some device
- To detect if a user using an application has yet another IAP purchased in another application of us, to let him see the map layer in this application too

I know that Apple let you get the identifier "identifierForVendor", that let you know if the same device is using an app of ours. But my problem is I don't know how to detect if the user install our app in another device, how can I detect if the user has some IAP purchased to talk to our server and show the IAP the user purchased in this app or another app.

There is no way to get some user identifier to do this communication?
Any help will be welcome :) Thanks for your time